# Check some part of string in variable in template Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Hi i got the site domain in the template name with the

> {{request.META.HTTP_HOST}}

from which i got the value some thing like this

> pydev.aviesta.com

and

> pydev.aviesta.com.mx

i need to show different data for both domains but as this is the dev server i cant use the full doamin name for compare can i check only .mx or .com so there will be no problem when going to live site

Answer (score 1):

You may need [Custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) for this.

```
@register.filter(name='split')
def split(value, arg):
    return value.split('.')[-1]
```

Use it as `{{request.META.HTTP_HOST|split}}`

Comment: i got the solution by using js something like this

Comment: I saw your solution, but you mentioned django, python!!

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution with js

```
<script>
 var str = location.host;
        if( str.search(".mx") > 0 ){
        var dom = 'mx';
        }else{
        var dom = 'com';
        } </script>
```

Comment: Why don't you do it in Django's way!

Comment: actually i am new to django may be thats why i prefer js for now